# chosen - search accented words

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm using [this plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) to beautify the select box. It has search function that when type it will filter out the result. The problem is that, if my select has words like á, é, í, ó, ú, ü, ñ, the plugin won't understand. For example: if I type a, it should assume I'm typing á, therefore give the results with words like a and á. But it did not. only gave me words with a.

So, doesn't anybody know how to make it understand accented word?

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/536

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are asking for is currently a feature request in the project:

https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/536

Although there isn't an official release that includes this functionality at the moment, some users have proposed working solutions you can try.

For example:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/whqb5/1/

Comment: This fixed my issue with double quotes in my select text!  The standard chosen.jquery.min.js was bugging out on the character 1 position left of the double quote.  I had an option with text of: Robert "Bob" Smith  The search field would correctly list the option in the results if I typed in Bo but when I typed Bob it disappeared from the list.  I copied the .js from the fiddle and the flaw is gone. Many thanks!

Comment: err, just got a javascript console error saying "RegExp too big".  Ugh, it appears this is not stable enough for my ~1000 option select.

Comment: @bmunslow http://fiddle.jshell.net/whqb5/1/ gives 404 error. Could you repost the solution? I'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding this code:

```js
var t=t.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
```

to the function `t.prototype.search_string_match=function(t,e)`

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to modify `get_search_regex` (input search value) and after that `search_string_match` (loops trough dropdown items).

Should you modify only the latter, you would filter matches out when accented characters are used in the input string.

Steps:

1. normalize input in `get_search_regex` -> at the beginning of the function add `t = t.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");`
   *(in minified js search for `t.prototype.get_search_regex=function(t){`)*
2. normalize dropdown items in `search_string_match` -> at the beginning of the function add `t = t.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");`
   *(in minified js search for `t.prototype.search_string_match=function(t,e)`)*

Explanation:

```
normalize("NFD")
```

Normalizes a string according to unicode normalization form. NFD stands for *Canonical Decomposition* and it "decomposes" unicode characters. For example `š` is decomposed into `ˇ` + `s`, `ﬀ` into `ff` and `Ⓓ` into `d`. Hence this is able to handle way more cases than a table one could come up with. Might be an overkill and you can always compose a table instead.

After we've normalized the string we are left with some characters we don't want (as in case of `š` we have `ˇ`). This is solved with regex that replaces all occurances of characters in range of `u0300` - `u036f` (which are known diacritical marks) with nothing (`""`).

```
replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")
```

[2021+ alternative of this would be to:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes)

```
replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, "")
```